# How to feed multi-channel spectrograms to Deep Neural Network?

Tags: fourier-transform, power-spectral-density, eeg, feature-extraction, deep-learning

I am using a 14 channel EEG device. To do away with the need for any handcrafted features, I wish to implement an ML classification task with the EEG data collected using deep neural networks (such as 2D-CNN) directly on the spectrograms.

I get decent results by **concatenating** all 14 spectrograms (per training example) side by side, to get a single spectrogram. Though this is the only thing that makes sense to me, what is the normal/right way to feed multi-channel spectrograms to a deep neural network?

Comment: I'd love to see someone on this stackexchange answer your question, but according to [this post on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms) your best bet is probably [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  Beyond that -- I don't think that there is an established-enough art for there to _be_ a "normal" way to do it, and the "right" way probably depends on the nature of the data and what information you want to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenation is how this is usually handled, but usually you view your data a as a stack of spectrograms. If you have `C` channels each with, then for each channel you compute a spectrogram with `L` time steps, and `N` bins per timestep, then an established way to view the input as a tensor of shape `(N, C, L)`, this is the convention used for instance in [pytorch convolutions](https://pytorch.org/docs/2.0/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html#conv1d).